# Related Event not showing up on Custom Object Related List

Tags: apex, trigger, event

I am trying to auto create Salesforce Event record when a custom object is created

[image]

And here is my code:

```
trigger CreatePTOEvent on Thrive_HR_PTO_Request__c (after insert) {
// Event is created when PTO Request record is created
List<Event> ptoevents = new List<Event>();
List<Thrive_HR_PTO_Request__c> ptorequest = Trigger.new;

for(Thrive_HR_PTO_Request__c ptr : ptorequest) {

    datetime StartDate = ptr.Start_Date__c;
    datetime EndDate = ptr.End_Date__c;
    date StartDateOnly = StartDate.date(); 
    date EndDateOnly = EndDate.date();

    Integer daysDifference = StartDateOnly.daysBetween(EndDateOnly);

    if(daysDifference < 14) {
        Event evt = new Event(Ownerid=ptr.CreatedById, WhatId=ptr.Id, 
                       Subject=ptr.Subject__c,StartDateTime=ptr.Start_Date__c, 
                       EndDateTime=ptr.End_Date__c, ActivityDateTime=ptr.Start_Date__c,
                       ActivityDate=ptr.Start_Date__c.date(),IsAllDayEvent=true);

    // add events to record
    ptoevents.add(evt);

    }
    else if (daysDifference >= 14) {
        ptr.End_Date__c.addError('You can not exceed more than 14 days');
    }
}
insert ptoevents;
```

}

When I put IsAllDayEvent=true, the even shows up in the related list:

[image]

But when I take that out, because I want the Event record to have Date and Time—it creates those records but it doesn't show up in my related record.

[image]

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: did you try to insert an Event in the UI, then query the database values using SFDC Workbench, Developer Console, or Eclipse to see how they compare to the Event you insert through Apex?

Comment: How did you set the Start and End Dates? You only showed the Open Activities related list, they may appear in the Activity History related list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the end date of an Event passes it is automatically moved to the **Activity History** related list, unlike Tasks which remain in the **Open Activities** related list until you close them.

In your first screenshot it shows that you're creating your Event with the current date and time. This means that when you save the record the end date/time has already passed and so it will be in **Activity History** list and not **Open Activities**.

Set an end date/time a little way in the future and your Event should show up.